# Is there a way to delete all numbers that are in a list (Notepad++)

Tags: notepad++

I have a list of around 800 numbers. I want to delete all numbers from that list that correspond with numbers in a different file. I know I can individually just search and replace all the numbers individually, but that would take an obscene amount of time. Do I have to do it individually or is there a way to delete all those numbers simultaneously?

EDIT: I only want to delete numbers from a certain selection.

Comment: If you're familiar with any programming language, then you better go for it. You can achieve the same via .bat / .sh command files for Windows / Linux

Comment: I don't know how to program sadly.

Comment: If you have access to a linux machine, you might be able to do what you want with `comm` or `join`. It depends on uniformity of the lines. You don't need to know how to program if the lines are uniform. All you need to know is how to build off of someone else's work (i.e., reading the man pages for the commands). That's what is so powerful about linux.

Comment: I do not have a Linux machine either. Darn.

Comment: Alternative: get those number lists in two Excel sheets, and add a column that will find a match of the row's value in the other sheet.

Comment: Alternative2: filter out all numbers to consider (one per line) so you only have those in your first file. Paste the other set of numbers at the end of the first list. Sort the whole list. Identify which pairs of lines have the same numbers.

Comment: Alternative 3: hire a programmer.

Comment: 1) Open the file that contains the list of numbers. 2) join all numbers with pipe `|`. 3) Copy the line. 4) Open the file. 5) Ctrl+H 6) Paste in the box "Find what".7) Leave "Replace with" empty. 8) Click on "Replace all".